# Changing currency decimal positions in mysql

Tags: mysql, decimal, currency

I am storing some currency values in my mysql database, I currently have the field type set to decimal(10,2) which gives me prices of £2.22 . I need to change it so it is formatted like this £1.3044  . Every time I input a value of 1.3044 to saves the value 1.30 to the database, does anyone know the correct type to display something like this ? £1.3044

EDIT >>>>

After following the answer below, this now works and saves the data in the correct format, the problem is now, for some reason when it re loads it into the form field it changes it to 1.30 even though in the database it is 1.3044.

```
    <div class="oilprices" style="width:800px; height:auto; float:left;margin-left:15px;">
      <div style="float:left; width:235px "><span class="ccms_form_element cfdiv_text" id="oilpricegasoil"><strong><span style="font-weight:bold;margin-top:4px; float:left;"><span style="font-size:15px; padding-right:10px;">Oil Prices -   </span> Gas Oil</span> £</strong>
          <input name="oilpricegasoil" style="padding:3px !important; background:#fff;" type="text" class="form-field" id="oilpricegasoil" title="oilpricegasoil" size="3" maxlength="10" label_over="0" hide_label="0" /><span style="padding-left:2px;">PPL</span>
    </span></div>
      <div style="float:left; width:130px; margin-left:5px; "><span class="ccms_form_element cfdiv_text" id="oilpricegasoil"><strong>Derv £</strong>
          <input name="oilpricederv" type="text" style="background:#fff;padding:3px !important;" class="form-field" id="oilpricederv" title="oilpricederv" size="3" maxlength="10" label_over="0" hide_label="0" /><span style="padding-left:2px;">PPL</span>
    </span></div>
      <div style="float:left; width:135px; margin-left:5px; "><span class="ccms_form_element cfdiv_text" id="oilpricegasoil"><strong>Kero £</strong>
          <input name="oilpricekero" style="background:#fff;padding:3px !important;" type="text" class="form-field" id="oilpricekero" title="oilpricekero" size="3" maxlength="10" label_over="0" hide_label="0" /><span style="padding-left:2px;">PPL</span>
    </span></div>
    <input name="cf_id" type="hidden" id="cf_id" value="">
    <div style="width:40px; float:left;padding-left:10px"> 

        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Update">

    </div>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the data type to `decimal(10,4)`

Comment: Thanks, this works now, well kind of, if I type in 1.3044 it saves it to the database correctly now, if I go to the database the data is correctly saved as 1.3044 , but for some odd reason when it loads the data back into the form field it displays it as 1.30 even though in the db it is 1.3044

Comment: @IainSimpson my question will be, how are you loading this value in the HTML? what server side language are you using?